# How to graph ranges vs other ranges in Excel?

Tags: excel, plot, graph, data-visualization

I'm looking for something like a horizontal clustered bar graph, but instead of categories on the y-axis, I would like ranges there as well. For example, one bar that goes from 1 to 3 on the x-axis is plotted from 10 to 20 on the y-axis, etc. I've linked a screenshot of what I need below. Thanks, everybody!
[image: example-graph]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fake it with a scatter chart if you create the four corners of each rectangle, repeat the starting point and leave an empty row between each set of data:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is a solid hack. I'll try it out an see how it looks.